# How can we centralise a non-central chi squared random variable?

Tags: random-variable, chi-squared-distribution, non-central

Say that $X\sim {\chi '}_{k}^{2}(\lambda)$ and $Y \sim \chi_k$. What transformation of $X$ will produce $Y$?

If we also let $Z \sim N(\mu, 1)$, $\lambda = \mu^2$, and $k=1$, then I understand that $(Z - \mu)^2 = Y$ and $Z^2 = X$, but how can I apply this transformation without knowledge of the original $Z$?

Answer (score 3):

The generic answer is to use the cdf and the inverse cdf, namely
$$Y=F^{-1}_{k,0}(F_{k,\lambda}(X))$$
where $F_{k,\lambda}(\cdot)$ is the $\chi^2_k(\lambda)$ cdf.

Comment: This is a bit *too* generic, I think.

Comment: Especially because both the CDF of noncentral $\chi^2$ and the Percent Point Function of $\chi^2$ are very complex

Comment: The problem is that the *question* is too generic.  There are a huge number of possible transformations that will work.  The one given here by Xi'an is powerful and obviously works for all $k$ and $\lambda.$  Although there exist simpler transformations in special cases (such as $k=1$), they are not fully general. Could you provide some motivation or constraints to limit the scope of answers?